# C# class type - How to determine whether it is a standard .net framework class

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

C# / .net framework

What is the most reliable way to determine whether a class (type) is a class provided by the .net framework and not any of my classes or 3rd party library classes.

I have tested some approaches

- The namespace, e.g. starting with "System."
- The Codebase of the assembly, where the dll is located

All this "feels" a little clumsy though it works.

Question: What is the easiest and most reliable way to determine this?

Comment: You'd probably want to start by defining what it is you mean by a "standard" framework class.  If you can actually answer that, the rest should be easy...

Comment: I have added a comment regarding this below. Thanks for pointing is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Assembly Company Attribute from the assembly
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft Corporation")]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1375e30.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CustAttrs1CS")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("GetCustomAttributes() Demo")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]

namespace CustAttrs1CS {
    class DemoClass {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Type clsType = typeof(DemoClass);
            // Get the Assembly type to access its metadata.
            Assembly assy = clsType.Assembly;

            // Iterate through the attributes for the assembly.
            foreach(Attribute attr in Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(assy)) {
                // Check for the AssemblyTitle attribute.
                if (attr.GetType() == typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute))
                    Console.WriteLine("Assembly title is \"{0}\".",
                        ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)attr).Title);

                // Check for the AssemblyDescription attribute.
                else if (attr.GetType() == 
                    typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute))
                    Console.WriteLine("Assembly description is \"{0}\".",
                        ((AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attr).Description);

                // Check for the AssemblyCompany attribute.
                else if (attr.GetType() == typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute))
                    Console.WriteLine("Assembly company is {0}.",
                        ((AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attr).Company);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used a combination of 

1.) The "Company Attribute" and 
2.) "Strongname / token" answer 

to solve my issues. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: This dont means that is .NET Standart class. Many classes come with .NET but not is Standart. And other .NET implementation like Mono have another Company Name

Comment: Yes, you are right. "Standard" meant something specific in my very application context, however the "company attribute" / "token answer" helped to improve my detection method. Academically my definition is not precise / ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

You could check the assembly's public key token.  Microsoft (BCL) assemblies will have the public key token `b77a5c561934e089` or `b03f5f7f11d50a3a`.  WPF assemblies will have the public key token `31bf3856ad364e35`.

In general, to get the public key token of an assembly, you can use [`sn.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx)`-Tp foo.dll`.  `sn.exe` is part of the Windows SDK, which you should already have.

You can get the public key token from the assembly's full name (e.g. `typeof(string).Assembly.FullName`), which is just a string, or you can get the raw public key token bytes from the assembly by doing a P/Invoke into [StrongNameTokenFromAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230157(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I have used a combination of 

1.) The "Company Attribute" and 
2.) "Strongname / token" answer 

to solve my issues. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

In Visual Studio, within Solution Explorer, expand References, right click a reference, then choose Properties and look at the path, example:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll

I'm guessing that most assemblies in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ are likely to be standard .NET.

Also, you could look up the assembly in MSDN library, example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx.

Answer (score -2):

You say about Base Class Library?

You can consult here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library